# Match exact word with any character regex

Tags: php, regex

How to match exact word contains any special character ?

```
$string = 'Fall in love with #PepsiMoji! Celebrate #WorldEmojiDay by downloading our keyboard @ http://bit.ly/pepsiKB & take your text game up a notch. - teacher';

preg_match("/\b#worldemojiday\b/i",$string); //false
```

I want to match exact word containing any character. Like if I want to match word 'download' in this string, It should return false

```
preg_match("/\bdownload\b/i",$string); //false
```

But when I search for downloading, It should return true.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `\b` word boundary before `#` non-word character. `\b` cannot match the position between 2 non-word (or between 2 word) characters, thus, you do not get a match.

A solution is either to remove the first `\b`, or use `\B` (a non-word boundary matching between 2 word or 2 non-word characters) instead of it.

```
\B#worldemojiday\b
```

Or

```
#worldemojiday\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dO1gM0/1) (or [this one](https://regex101.com/r/dO1gM0/2))

Note that `\B` also matches at the beginning of a string.

Here is [a way](http://ideone.com/B35WnB) to build a regex dynamically, adding word boundaries only where necessary:

```
$srch = "žvolen";
$srch = preg_quote($srch);
if (preg_match('/\w$/u', $srch)) {
    $srch .= '\\b';   
}

if (preg_match('/^\w/u', $srch)) {
    $srch = '\\b' . $srch;
}
echo preg_match("/" . $srch . "/ui", "žvolen is used.");
```

Comment: The problem with this regex is when I try to find celebrate it does not match. I want something that can find an exact word with word boundary.

Comment: If you are building the regex dynamically, you need to check for the first and final characters of the search string. If the character is a word character, add `\b`. If not, add `\B` or nothing. Please post your actual code.

Comment: @stribizhev Would you please tell me what characters are covered by word boundary ?

Comment: Word boundary characters are letters, digits, and an underscore. To enable Unicode word boundary support, you'd need to use `/u` modifier.

Comment: If I try to find whether it's the character in word boundary or not using '/\w/', will this work ?

Like

preg_match('/\w/i','#');

Comment: I think you can have a look at [this fiddle](http://ideone.com/B35WnB). Sorry, it took me long.

Comment: Sorry, the below answer is perfect by @jonny-5

Comment: @RohitKhatri: Please do not change your mind that quickly. `(?<=\W)#WorldEmojiDay(?=\W)` is also working in PHP. You tried it at [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) that only supports JavaScript regex flavor, but instead, you should have tried it at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) that **supports PHP regex (PCRE)**. Unless you need to support both regex flavors and you do not care about Unicode, I'd prefer Jonny's solution.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!\w)#WorldEmojiDay(?!\w)
```

This ensures, that there's no *word character* before or after the string. See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bD9nM9/1)

Comment: This is the exact answer I was looking for.

Comment: tried in regexr.com but it gave error. just add '!' after '?' in '(?<!\w)'

Comment: @RohitKhatri sure this works in php/pcre :] see [the regex101 demo that I provided in answer](https://regex101.com/r/bD9nM9/1). Of course in php need to put that into delimiters and add your `i` flag for caseless matching: `/(?<!\w)#WorldEmojiDay(?!\w)/i`